# How to add path to pathfinder?

Tags: path, atk4

I want to make different panel for administrator. I created a folder 'Admin' and I put in there index.php, and folder 'lib' with Frontend.php and Auth.php. In admin panel's pages I want to make use of models, templates etc from my main folder. How can I add this to path finder? Folder structure

1. MainSite

   1. Admin

      1. lib

         1. Frontend.php
         2. Auth.php
      2. index.php
      3. config.php
   2. atk4
   3. atk4-addons
   4. lib(Models which I want to use, Forms ect, Frontend.php, Auth.php)
   5. pages
   6. templates
   7. config.php
   8. index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this into your application init()

```
$this->addLocation('..',array(
    'php'=>array(
        'lib',
        'atk4-addons/mvc',
        'atk4-addons/misc/lib',
    ),
    'template'=>'templates',
    'mail'=>'templates/mail',  // if you want to share mail templates
))->setParent($this->pathfinder->base_location);
```

Also be sure to use

```
$config['atk']['base_path']='/atk4/';
```

and your index.php needs to include '../atk4/loader.php';